Xampp Control Panel no funciona
He instalado xampp para linux siguiendo el manual de xampp. Al intentar iniciar el panel de control de xampp, me devuelve el siguiente error:
euricky@penguin:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run

No protocol specified

No protocol specified

Unknown Error couldn't connect to display ":0"

Xampp me funciona cuando lo inicio (sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start), es el control panel el que no funciona.
Estoy usando debian, no se si es problema del sistema. Lo que sé es que al abrir el archivo manager-linux-x64.run con nano:

Cómo lo puedo arreglar?
Gracias de antemano

Has probado con LAMP?? Pueda que sea mejor puesto que es exactamente para Linux

Prueba ejecutando el siguiente comando en la terminal:
export DISPLAY=":0"
A mi me funcionó a la primera, espero que también te sirva.
